# UIkit 2 - How trigger pagination page

Tags: getuikit

I have a function "go to" in my page, I already tried to update "currentPage" property in the instance but this doesn't worked.

Once UIkit doesn't have a specific method to change page, there is a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, diging a little more into the files of the lib, I found a method "selectPage" that is available in the instance.

```
this.pagination = UIkit.pagination('.uk-pagination');
this.pagination.options.items = itemsCount;
this.pagination.options.itemsOnPage = itemsPerPage;
this.pagination.init();

this.pagination.selectPage(parseInt(this.goToPage - 1, 10));
```